# how to get the lowercase string and digit string from the string line then put them into a List?

Tags: scala

how to get the lowercase string and digit string from the string line then put them into a List

```
val s: String = "ab12%3kk45@"
```

expect:

```
val result: List[String] = List("ab","12","3","kk","45")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
scala> val result = """[0-9]+|[a-z]+""".r.findAllIn(s).toList
result: List[String] = List(ab, 12, 3, kk, 45)
```

This expression matches either a continuous substring of digits with `[0-9]+`, or  a continuous substring of lowercase letters with `[a-z]+`, and `findAllIn` method finds all such substrings.

Comment: Wow, this solution is just awesome.

Comment: Simply elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fun answer(*As I'm preparing for CS interview :) no utility methods*). The idea is simply create keep buffering the characters that fall into the same ascii range.

As soon as you see something that does not fall into same ascii range, add current buffer to list

```
def extractIsomorphicChars(input: String): ListBuffer[String] = {

  var previousChar = ' '

  var ismorphicList = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]

  var isomorphicChars = ""

  input.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (currentChar, index) =>

    if ((48 to 57 contains currentChar.toInt) ||
      (65 to 90 contains currentChar.toInt) ||
      (97 to 122 contains currentChar.toInt)) {

      if (index == 0) {
        isomorphicChars = isomorphicChars + currentChar
      } else if (
        (List(currentChar.toInt, previousChar.toInt) forall (48 to 57).contains) ||
          (List(currentChar.toInt, previousChar.toInt) forall (65 to 90).contains) ||
          (List(currentChar.toInt, previousChar.toInt) forall (97 to 122).contains)) {
        isomorphicChars = isomorphicChars + currentChar
        if (index == input.length - 1) {
          ismorphicList += isomorphicChars
        }
      } else {
        if (isomorphicChars.nonEmpty) {
          ismorphicList += isomorphicChars
          isomorphicChars = ""
        }
        isomorphicChars = isomorphicChars + currentChar
      }

    } else if (isomorphicChars.nonEmpty) {
      ismorphicList += isomorphicChars
      isomorphicChars = ""
    }

    previousChar = currentChar
  }
  ismorphicList
}
```

Tests

```
extractIsomorphicChars("ab12%3kk45@") shouldBe ListBuffer("ab", "12", "3", "kk", "45")
extractIsomorphicChars("aaaaaa") shouldBe ListBuffer("aaaaaa")
extractIsomorphicChars("123456") shouldBe ListBuffer("123456")
extractIsomorphicChars("") shouldBe ListBuffer()
extractIsomorphicChars("abc ") shouldBe ListBuffer("abc")
extractIsomorphicChars("%%     ") shouldBe ListBuffer()
extractIsomorphicChars(">%%%<") shouldBe ListBuffer()
```